# Eliminating View Angles in Processing

Tags: processing, simulation, microcontroller

I'm working on a Quad-copter and for testing purposes I have decided to use Processing to give  me a visual example of what the micro-controller is processing and calculating (and possibly some control algorithm simulation later on). So I have made a simple model of a Quad-copter and was displaying it in the upper right of my screen. In the "rest position," I want a perfect side view of the Quad-copter, like this:

[image]

Instead, I get an image like this:

[image]

The second image was when I rendered the Quad in the upper right, and the first is when I rendered it dead center in the window.

I understand what is happening here but I don't know how to fix it. The rendering system assumes my point of view is dead center in the screen, so anything up and to the right of my point of view is seen from underneath and in the front a little. I poked around on the Reference tab on their website and nothing seems to do exactly what I want. I would think that there would be a solution to this, but I currently can't find one.Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? You could use a simple cube instead of a full model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the `ortho()` function. You can read about it in the reference [here](https://www.processing.org/reference/ortho_.html).

> Sets an orthographic projection and defines a parallel clipping volume. All objects with the same dimension appear the same size, regardless of whether they are near or far from the camera.

Consider this little example program without calling the `ortho()` function:

```java
void setup(){
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  translate(300, 100);
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  box(100, 100, 100);
}
```

[image]

Now let's add the call to the `ortho()` function:

```java
void setup(){
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  translate(300, 100);
  ortho();
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  box(100, 100, 100);
}
```

[image]

You now no longer see the "depth" of the square. You can add parameters to the `ortho()` function to make it do exactly what you want, but those are the basics.

Alternatively, you could do something like setup a view that you draw to the middle of, and then draw that view in the upper-right corner of your main view.